# How to define static method classes in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Although I've used Javascript for many years, I'm completely a newbie in terms of all the popular frameworks and libraries.  And I have lots of questions about "packages" in that general sense:  It would be nice to find a cheatsheet that lists all the general purpose toolkits like JQuery as well as the specialized solutions.  But my transition is gradual, and I'm still "rolling my own".

In terms of rolling my own:  How can I create classes in Javascript that are not intended to be instantiated in order to bundle static methods?  eg:

```
var mypackage = new Object ;
mypackage.getDocument = function () {
    return document ;
}.bind( mypackage ) ;

mypackage.getCookie = function () {
    return this.getDocument().cookie ;
    }.bind( mypackage ) ;
```

*This example is intentionally trivial, please do not respond with alternatives for retrieving a document cookie.*

This example demonstrates my typical approach to define a *class* or *package* in Javascript.  But I understand that the bind() operator is relatively new and may not be suitable for production.  Is that true?  Are there alternative approaches?

Comment: `var mypackage = { getDocument: function() { ... }, getCookie: function() { ... } }`?

Comment: There's a pretty good e-book on Javascript design patterns that might help you out. http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/

Comment: Javascript does not have classes. It does have a prototype-driven OO system. I think you're actually asking for _namespaces_, though.

Comment: You don't need `bind` in that code.

Answer (score 3):

I often see them initialized as an object, and do this as well. An example would be:

```
// Definition.
var mypackage = {
    getDocument: function () {
        return document;
    },

    getCookie: function () {
        return this.getDocument().cookie;
    }
};

// Example.
(function () {
    console.log(mypackage.getCookie());
}());
```